# How to create single item select mvx list in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

So I am creating android app with Xamarin and MvvmCross. I need to make a list which shows all items, and you can select only one item. If you already selected one item and try to select another, then the first item is no longer selected and new one is selected.

List view model:

```
    public class ManagedPagesSelectViewModel : SharedViewModel
    {
        private ICollection<ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel> _pages;

        public ICollection<ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel> Pages { get => _pages; set => SetProperty(ref _pages, value); }

        public ManagedPagesSelectViewModel() : base(navigation)
        {
        }

        public override async Task Initialize()
        {
            var tempPages = new Collection<ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel>();
            await base.Initialize();
            IsLoading = true;

            try
            {

                tempPages.Add(new ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel { Name = "testName", PhotoUrl = "asdasdasd", AccessToken = "asdasdasdasdasd" });
                tempPages.Add(new ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel { Name = "testName1", PhotoUrl = "asdasdasd1", AccessToken = "asdasdasdasdasd1" });

                Pages = tempPages;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error = "Could not load managed pages list";
            }

            IsLoading = false;
        }    
    }
```

Item view model:

```
public class ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _name;
    private string _url;
    private string _accessToken;
    private bool _isSelected;

    public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    public string PhotoUrl { get => _url; set => SetProperty(ref _url, value); }
    public string AccessToken { get => _accessToken; set => SetProperty(ref _accessToken, value); }
    public bool IsSelected { get => _isSelected; set => SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value); }

    public IMvxCommand SelectCommand => new MvxCommand(SelectCommandHandler);

    public void SelectCommandHandler()
    {
        IsSelected = !IsSelected;
    }
}
```

list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
       <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:paddingTop="50dp">
       <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/managedpagelistitem"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Pages"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
</RelativeLayout>
```

And list item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
local:MvxBind="Click SelectCommand"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/block"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        local:MvxBind="Text Name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <CheckBox
        local:MvxBind="Checked IsSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? I just can't figure out how to remove `IsSelected` from old item if new is selected....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put your SelectCommand in your `ManagedPagesSelectViewModel` with the item and toggle the selection accordingly, also to save the selection and taking into account to toggle its selection to `false` before selecting the current item:

```
public class ManagedPagesSelectViewModel : SharedViewModel
{
    ...

    private ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel lastSelectedItem;

    public MvxCommand<ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel> SelectCommand => new MvxCommand<ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel>(SelectCommandHandler);

    public void SelectCommandHandler(ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel  item)
    {
        if(this.lastSelectedItem != null)
            this.lastSelectedItem.IsSelected = false;

        item.IsSelected = !item.IsSelected;
        this.lastSelectedItem = item;
    }    
}
```

Also we have to bind it in the `ItemClick` as follows:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/managedpagelistitem"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Pages; ItemClick SelectCommand"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Another way is with the same binding in the select command handler "unselect" all the items and select the current one:

```
public class ManagedPagesSelectViewModel : SharedViewModel
{
    ...

    public MvxCommand<ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel> SelectCommand => new MvxCommand<ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel>(SelectCommandHandler);

    public void SelectCommandHandler(ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel  item)
    {
        foreach(ManagedPagesSelectItemViewModel i in this.Pages)
            i.IsSelected = false;

        item.IsSelected = !item.IsSelected;
    }    
}
```

HIH

Comment: The command you wrote is getting a parameter item. Shouldn't there be a parameter bind in the view? Because currently, I've tried your approach and it's not working. The command is not called on the item click.

Comment: Never mind to first comment, I noticed that everything works, when I remove checkboxes from the item view.